# How to analyze the solution of the differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

[image]This is a mcq question and asks me to check whether the solution of

$\frac{dy}{dx} = a.y(x) - by^2(x) $ where $y(0)=y_0$ and $ a$ and $b$ are positive numbers.

(A)If $x \to \infty$ then $y \to \frac{a}{b}$ if $y_0>0$

(C) if $y_0=0$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty} y(x)=0$

(D) if $y_0<0$ then the solution is unbounded when $x$ tends to some value.

We can convert this equation to linear by taking $z = \frac{1}{y}$

Then the solution is $\frac{1}{y} = \frac{b}{a} + (\frac{1}{y_0} + \frac{b}{a}).e^{-ax}$

Case 1: If $x \to \infty$ then $e^{-ax} \to 0$ then $y \to \frac{a}{b}$

Case 2: If $y_0 =0$ then $y = \frac{y_0}{\frac{b}{a}y_0 + (1+y_0.\frac{b}{a})e^{-ax})} = 0$

Case 3: if $y_0 < 0$
Assume that $y_0 = -1$ then at $x = \frac{ln(1- \frac{b}{a}) + ln(\frac{b}{a})}{a}$ we see that $y$ tends to $\infty$

So i think all the options are true.

Comment: Is there a question?